# How to corrupt a file writing to it from multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, file, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am writing a function to save data to a file. It may be called with the same parameters (same data, same file) at the same time from multiple threads or processes. This is a scenario which I cannot avoid, so I am writing unit tests to ensure it does not lead to data corruption.

In order to trust my unit tests I would like to test that they fail with a poorly written function. I did not succeed, my file always contains the expected data.

Here is a way to reproduce the (lack of) problem. The file `test.txt` always contains `CONTENT`.

```
import io
import threading

# 1,000,000 lines: Test #0, Test #1, ..., Test #999999. About 13Mb.
CONTENT = ''.join(['Test #' + str(i) + "\n" for i in range(1000000)]).encode()

# Thread to write CONTENT to test.txt
class WriteThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        stream = io.BytesIO(CONTENT)
        with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
            for buffer in iter(lambda: stream.read(), b''):
                f.write(buffer)

# Run 100 write threads in parallel
threads = []
for i in range(100):
    threads.append(WriteThread())
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Am I doing it wrong? Am I lucky? Is this a behaviour I should rely on?

Comment: Umm... `for buffer in iter(lambda: stream.read(), b''): f.write(buffer)` is equivalent to `f.write(stream.read())`, because you didn't actually read blocks, you just read the whole damn file, then got nothing the second call. I can't figure out what you think you're testing, since writing the exact same thing to independently opened handles to the same file will just populate and truncate the same file a bunch and end with the same data regardless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: The filesystem is allowed to break up and reorder writes, *possibly* in a way that could break this (but I'm skeptical).

Comment: The loop is there because I call `stream.read(BUFFER_SIZE)` in my real code. I should have cleaned up better. So are you saying I can open N `'w'` handles to the same file and not worry? What will the file contain then, what I wrote to the last closed handle?

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah, I'm not sure if it's technically possible to cause corruption, but frankly, a bunch of monolithic `open` and single bulk `write`s of the exact same data seem the worst way to hit it even if it is possible.

Comment: @marcv81: Every time you open a handle with `'w'`, it truncates the file.  So whichever write happens last will (probably) determine the file contents, unless some other write gets scheduled after the last truncate...

Comment: @marcv81: If you're writing bits and pieces, you could end up with some weird behaviors depending on system. Each `open` with `w` will truncate the file, but the file pointer for threads that have already written something may continue to point far off, and writing at that point might force the data before it to be filled with zeroes. If all the threads write the same data, when it all settles down you probably won't notice anything weird (no guarantees), but as you run, the file might be sparsely populated with blocks separated by zero-initialized gaps.

Comment: If you want to ensure only one thread determines the canonical contents of a file, have them each open a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` in the same directory as the "real" name, populate it, `flush` it (possibly call `os.sync()` to make sure everything is really on disk), then call `os.replace` to rename it to the "real" name. `os.replace` is atomic, so if you only `rename` from fully populated files, the last to do the `rename` will be the sole thread defining its contents.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You want `os.fsync()` or even `os.fdatasync()`.  `os.sync()` might go off and fiddle with some network-mounted filesystem that has nothing to do with the files you're trying to synchronize.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: what you suggest is exactly what I implemented. It's `os.rename` by the way, and it is only atomic if the temp file is on the same partition. I would just be happier with it if I could get a bad implementation to fail.

Comment: @Kevin: I was going for overkill. :-) `os.fdatasync()` makes sense, but you know, what if the directory metadata hasn't been updated. Things could happen! I don't know what things, but I live in perpetual fear of them! If only everyone had [`syncfs(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/syncfs), I could balance my paranoia with efficiency better. :-)

Comment: @marcv81: No, if you're on Python 3.3 or higher, [you want `os.replace` for portability](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace). `os.rename` doesn't have consistent semantics between Windows and Linux when the target name already exists, while `os.replace` has guaranteed overwrite behavior. The same partition requirement is why I mentioned making the temporary file in the same directory as the "real" file, as that (should) guarantee that the tempfile and the real file are on the same partition.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I stand corrected, thanks.